# JSON exception during MongoDB deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, .net-6.0

I am encountering a 'System.Text.Json.JsonException' with the message "'O' is an invalid start of a value" while attempting to deserialize MongoDB BSON documents using the ASP.NET Core MongoDB driver. The issue arises when using JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync method. I have verified the JSON structure and MongoDB documents but am still facing this problem. Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
–
ps: I'm currently saving JSON documents with a dynamic schema , that's why i followed that approach

```
System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'O' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $._id | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 10.
 ---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: 'O' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 10.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte marker)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Skip()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& state, JsonReaderException ex)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, Nullable`1 actualByteCount)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](String json, JsonSerializerOptions options)
```

```
  [HttpGet("{id}")]
  public async Task<ActionResult<ProjectIdentification>> GetProjectById(string id)
  {

      var project = await _projectService.GetProjectById(id);
      if (project == null)
      {
          return NotFound();
      }
      return Ok(project.ToJson());
  }
```

```
   public class ProjectIdentification
   {

       [BsonId]
       [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
       public string? Id { get; set; } = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();

       public string? version { get; set; }
       public Object[] content { get; set; }
       public Object[] columns { get; set; }
       public Theme theme { get; set; }

   }
```

```
     public async Task AddProject(ProjectIdentification project)
  {
      string serializedJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(project, new JsonSerializerOptions
      {
          DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull
      });

      BsonDocument bsonDocument = BsonDocument.Parse(serializedJson);

      await _collection.InsertOneAsync(bsonDocument);
  }

  public async Task<ProjectIdentification> GetProjectById(string id)
  {
      var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", ObjectId.Parse(id));
      var result = await _collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
      Console.Write(result);
      if (result != null)
      {
          return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ProjectIdentification>(result.ToJson());
      }

      return null;
  }
```

I attempted to deserialize MongoDB BSON documents here is a data example :

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid": "65edc0c6482da8bd8368fbbf" },
  "Id": "65edc0c6482da8bd8368fbbe",
  "content": [
    {
      "id": "z5LllRt-NoiGkoisa_2tN",
      "type": "image",
      "data": {
        "style": "circle",
        "image": "/images/profile.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "QfAFa0golVKIImL764OCO",
      "type": "text",
      "data": {
        "headline": "Horst Karacho",
        "description": "My name is Horst :)",
        "rank":"test",
        "anotherfield":"tesst"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "j3ofcLmYExoG0AS_yoRq0",
      "type": "text",
      "data": {
        "headline": "Lorem Ipsum",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna...",
        "details": {
          "author": "Unknown",
          "publishedDate": "2023-01-15",
          "wordCount": 245
        }
      }
    },
    
  ],
  "columns": [
    {
      "id": "mOceUBR-oB5xEzfstycFh",
      "content": [
        "qkx4WlS5XkUZcfTpy9rN0",
        "qkx4WlS5XkUZcfTpy9rN1",
        "qkx4WlS5XkUZcfTpy9rN11",
        "qkx4WlS5XkUZcfTpy9rN12",
        "qkx4WlS5XkUZcfTpy9rN3",
        "qkx4WlS5XkUZcfTpy9rN4",
        "qkx4WlS5XkUZcfTpy9rN5",
        "qkx4WlS5XkUZcfTpy9rN6",
        "qkx4WlS5XkUZcfTpy9rN7",
        "qkx4WlS5XkUZcfTpy9rN8",
        "qkx4WlS5XkUZcfTpy9rN9"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "theme": {
    "HighlightColor": "#3f51b5",
    "HeadlineColor": "#95A5A6",
    "HeadlineFontType": "Roboto",
    "HeadlineFontSize": "1.8em",
    "HeadlineFontWeight": "600",
    "HeadlineBorderType": "dashed",
    "TextColor": "#333",
    "TextFontType": "Source Sans Pro",
    "TextFontSize": "1em",
    "TextFontWeight": "200"
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you work with `IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>` instead of `IMongoCollection<ProjectIdentification>`? With the latter, you could deserialize your document directly in the form of `ProjectIdentification` instead of reading a `BsonDocument`, converting it to JSON and then having the failure while deserializing the JSON.

Comment: I'm currently saving JSON documents with a dynamic schema  , that's why i followed that approach

Comment: 1. do not paste links on images, use plain text or plain images in worst case. 2. You do a mess, reading collection data as Bson (roughly equivalent to Json), then convert it to Json itself and then deserialize it to object => you should deserialize it into object in the first step. Same with writing. 3. `"'O' is an invalid start of a value` - I don't see how any of the above code can generate this error, you should provide more details, in particular data example that generate this error

Comment: I just updated with an example of my data

Comment: The dynamic part should be your `content` and `columns` fields only, not the whole document.